# Correctly rendering ActionLinks on MVC site with vanityURL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink

I need to create site where URL patterns allow for a personalized URL like `www.mysite.com` brings up the main portal.

`www.mysite.com/customer1` brings the portal customized for that customer (same actions and controllers called the argument for customization will be pulled from URL).

I want the prefix '/customer1/' to be maintained in the URL all the time on all pages.

I have the following routes which work fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CompanyUrl",
    url: "{companyurl}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { companyurl = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

However, when I enter the site on the vanityURL so on `www.mysite.com/customer1` all action links are rendered OK as

```
<a href="/customer1/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
```

but when I enter just `www.mysite.com`, all links are rendered as:

```
<a href="//Home/Testimonials">Testimonials</a>
```

and I cannot navigate anywhere.

How can I get them to render correctly without the `companyurl` parameter and without the additional `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood correctly, try this (though check if it works as expected throughout):

- remove the default for `{companyurl}` - this makes it "mandatory" for that route (meaning it will not "match" your `CompanyUrl` route config *if not present* and fall through next config which is the `Default` config).

So your "CompanyUrl" Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CompanyUrl",
    url: "{companyurl}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Hth...

Comment: Thank you that helped. I didn't realise having a default makes it mandatory, I've had some other problems after which disappeared when I added a contraint on the companyurl parameter